# How to start session with node-session

Tags: node.js, session

I have a node.js server with socket.io like this:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var server = require('http').createServer().listen( port );
var io = require('socket.io').listen( server );
var user = require('./p/a/t/h/user');
io.sockets.on('connection', function( socket ){
socket.on('login', function( data ){
      user.login( data, function ( err, res ) {

      });
   });
});
```

And id like to have some kind of session system which recognize logged in users (i choose [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-session) one).
So my `user` module look something like this:

```
var session = require('node-session');
session = new session({secret: 'secret-string','driver': 'file','files': process.cwd() + '/sessions','lifetime': 3600000,'expireOnClose': false});
module.exports = {
    login: function ( data, callback ) {
        session.sessionStart(  ); // ??
    }
};
```

How to start a session here and/or get the related session data from the session storage?

Answer (score 1):

Found a working solution.

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var server = require('http').createServer().listen( port );
var io = require('socket.io').listen( server );
var user = require('./p/a/t/h/user');
io.sockets.on('connection', function( socket ){
    socket.on('login', function( data ){
          user.login( socket, data, function ( err, res ) {

          });
    });
});
```

and in user.js:

```
var session = require('node-session');
session = new session({secret: 'secret-string'});
module.exports = {
login: function ( socket, data, callback ) {
    session.startSession( socket.request, socket.request.res, function() {
       user.session = socket.request.session;

    });
}
```

};

Hope it's helpful for someone.